# Easily seeing values of subsets of excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Often I have large excel formulas with 6+ layers of nesting. When debugging it would be very convenient to see the value of a subset of the formula e.g. see what one argument to OR is evaluating to. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: yup, split them into individual cells.  Or you can do `Evaluate Formula` on the formula tab

Comment: That's why I use helper columns for those intermediate results  - your final formula references then these helper columns. Furthermore it often helps to use tables with structured references so that column names are readable (tab insert > table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to select the subset of the formula within the formula bar and press F9. But be careful to press Escape to revert to the original formula - otherwise you overwrite it.

Note this does not work well with formula subsets that return large arrays.